# Automating Human Actions On YouTube

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, youtube

I'm currently working on a python project, the only problem is that I don't want to use selenium to perform tasks such as liking a youtube video or subscribing to a channel. Do any of you know good ways to do this that ISN'T selenium? Cheers!

Edit: I don't want to use the YouTube API since it limits me for how many actions I can take. I'm mainly looking for python modules that can interact with the YouTube webpage.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do on YouTube?

Comment: I'm wanting to perform everyday actions on YouTube. An example could be: 
liking a video,
writing a comment + posting the comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/subscriptions).

[Tutorial to start using it with Python](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input! I have used the YouTube API in the past but as it limits my actions with quota limits. I'm looking for a different module instead of selenium that can interact with the YouTube page. Thanks for responding though! :)